# Best way to print HashMap type ArrayList in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have a HashMap type ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> menlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

It reads a JSON file and parses the data like so:

```
public void Test1() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset("M.json"));
        JSONArray jarr = (JSONArray) obj.get("people");

        for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jin = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
            String fname = jin.getString("firstname");
            String lname = jin.getString("lastname");

            HashMap<String,String> man = new HashMap<>();

            man.put("firstname",fname);
            man.put("lastname",lname);

            menlist.add(worker);
        }

            Log.d("menlist",menlist.toString());
    }
```

As you can see i can print it on Log just fine but i want to be able to show the whole menlist on the UI,as in the xml Design file.
What is the best way to approach it and how do i implement it?

Comment: Do you want to show the list of men on the TextView? Another question, do you really need to use HashMap?

Comment: I want to show each key/value from the HashMap in the TextView. Why not HashMap? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Use OOP. Instead of a Map to represent a man, just make a Man class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you need to create the Man class :

```
public class Man {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Man (String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

After that, you need to use it inside your function like this :

```
public ArrayList<Man> getListOfMen() throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<Man> menlist = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset("M.json"));
    JSONArray jarr = (JSONArray) obj.get("people");

    for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++) {
        JSONObject jin = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
        String fname = jin.getString("firstname");
        String lname = jin.getString("lastname");

        Man man = new Man(fname, lname);

        menlist.add(man);
    }
    return menlist;
}
```

Now, you can use this function to create a String to show inside your TextView :

```
ArrayList<Man> list = getListOfMen();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    sb.append(list.get(i).getFirstName());
    sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(list.get(i).getLastName());
    sb.append("\n");
}
    
textView.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Ok this is a far better approach,no longer using HashMap.